# PHP script allowing empty (blank) fields to database

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

EDIT: Code modified to include $errors variable. Please let me know if this will work, thanks.

I am new to PHP and MySQL. I have the below php code inside my web form and I am having a problem with it inserting a new record into the database when any of the web fields are blank or improperly formatted.

I have error checking occuring that will display an error message in red after pressing Submit button AND data is either blank or improperly formatted. This part is working fine, the problem is that it still allows the record to post to the database when there are blank/improperly formatted values. I would like to add some scripting to check to see if any of the mandatory fields are blank or formatted improperly and if so, do not proceed with the SQL Insert. I would appreciate if someone can help me with what scripting I should add. Below is the code I am using, thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>  

<?php
<?php

 $errors = "false";
// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = $subErr = "";
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = $sub = $newrecord = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["Name"])) {
    $nameErr = "Name is required";
    $errors = "true";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["Name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
      $errors = "true"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["Email"])) {
    $emailErr = "Email is required";
    $errors = "true";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["Email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
      $errors = "true"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["Website"])) {
    $website = "";
  } else {
    $website = test_input($_POST["Website"]);
    // check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular expression also allows dashes in the URL)
    if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$website)) {
      $websiteErr = "Invalid URL";
      $errors = "true"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["Comment"])) {
    $comment = "";
  } else {
    $comment = test_input($_POST["Comment"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
    $genderErr = "Gender is required";
    $errors = "true";
  } else {
    $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
  }

if (empty($_POST["Subscription"])) {
    $subErr = "Subscription is required";
    $errors = "true"; }
 else {
    $sub = test_input($_POST["Subscription"]);
    }
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<h2>Southern Tier Daily News</h2>
<form method="post" action="Newspaper3.php">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true"/>

<img src="https://bloximages.newyork1.vip.townnews.com/dnews.com/content/tncms/custom/image/5eec4204-483e-11e6-93c8-97ef236dc6c5.jpg?_dc=1468334339" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:128px;height:128px;">
    <p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<fieldset>
 <legend>Newspaper Subscription Request</legend>  
  Name: <input type="text" name="Name" value="<?php echo $name;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  E-mail: <input type="text" name="Email" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Website: <input type="text" name="Website" value="<?php echo $website;?>">
  <span class="error"><?php echo $websiteErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Comment: <textarea name="Comment" rows="5" cols="40"><?php echo $comment;?></textarea>
  <br><br>
  Gender:
  <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female") echo "checked";?> value="female">Female
  <input type="radio" name="gender" <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male") echo "checked";?> value="male">Male
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $genderErr;?></span>
    <br><br>
  Subscription:
   <select name="Subscription">
       <option value=""></option>
   <option value="Daily">Daily</option>
   <option value="Evening">Evening</option>
   <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
   <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
</select> 
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $subErr;?></span>

  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
<br><br>
<a href="https://www.google.com/">Visit Admin Page</a>
 </fieldset>
</form>



<?php

 if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
    and $errors = "False"
    include('connect-mysql.php');



$fname = $_POST['Name'];
$femail = $_POST['Email'];
$fcomment = $_POST['Comment'];
$fsubsciption = $_POST['Subscription'];
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO subscriptions (Name, Email, Comment, Subscription) VALUES ('$fname',
'$femail', '$fcomment', '$fsubsciption')";

      if (!mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlinsert))  {
           die(mysqli_error($dbcon)); // and die('error inserting new record'); ;       

  }     // end of nested if statement

  // else
        $newrecord = "1 record added to the database";

}  // end of main if statement

?>

<?php

echo $newrecord

?>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be easier to store all error messages in one array. If the array is empty insert in database if the array is not empty show error message(s). Also note that you are wide open for an SQL-injection

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com/ gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli.

Comment: I think you could start by some better organization of your code to make it more clear/simple.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the validated field values in your SQL statement, rather than using the $_POST variables again - and if the field doesn't exist, don't run the query.

Alternatively, don't run the SQL statement if any errors were found at the beginning of the script.  To achieve this, I would do:

- set a variable `$errors` to false at the start of the script
- whenever any error is found, set the `$errors` variable to true
- at the end of the script, where you have `if (isset($_POST['submitted']))`, also check that `$errors` is false before you actually run the insert.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Lorna, I modified the code above to include the $errors variable. Could you let me know if this is correct (syntax, logic)? Thanks!

Comment: I'm getting syntax errors at the section of code where IF (isset($_POST['submitted']))     I'm including an And function hear to also check that $errors is false. I must have the syntax wrong though...?

Comment: @Kevin `if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
    and $errors = "False"` should be `if (isset($_POST['submitted']) && $errors == "false") {`. You'd put the 2nd bit outside the `if`'s brackets, it's `&&` not `and`, also `$errors = "False"` _sets_ the variable, but an `==` or `===` _compares the variable to the other value. (I'll leave it to you to google the difference between == and ===, it can be useful). Also it would be more robust to set $errors to the boolean `true` and `false` values, rather than the string `"True"` and `"False"` values. Not least because of casing - `"false" != "False"`!

Comment: @Kevin it may be worth taking the time to study some of the basics of PHP syntax. Also your code above is not very logical, you randomly break up the PHP with a bit of markup, which is odd because it doesn't really reflect the flow of the program.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for the correct syntax and additional info. This now works as expected!

Answer (score 0):

In the above code your not checking for invalid data before inserting. Your just checking for the errors and bypassing it and storing in db. So modified the if condition as below.

if (isset($_POST['submitted']) && empty($err_array))

In $err_array store the error values instead of individual variables.

Comment: Thanks.  Would you mind sharing how and where in the script I should define the array and what values to insert in it? This is new to me and I havent worked with arrays.

Comment: if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
    and $errors = "False"   update this line as below.   if(isset($_POST['submitted'] ) && $errors == "False")    this will also solves ur problem

Answer (score 0):

I separated out your php from your html for clarity. First and most important, as was pointed out above you are vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks please use tokenized parameters and prepared statements to help protect yourself from this issue (example below).

On to your question, I would suggest trying to add some exception handling to your workflow. This might seem a bit intimidating if you are just starting out, but as long as you know where your error log files are for your dev server it offers a quick and concise way to see what is going wrong that will also serve you in an eventual production environment.

As far as handling empty form fields you can take a multichannel approach here, [HTML5 forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation) let you specify a field as required and block execution for invalid forms. [Javascript validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation#Constraint_API%27s_element.setCustomValidity()) is another option on the client side. It is always good to validate and sanitize your data on the server side as well though, and for this php has a few useful tools ([filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php), [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php)) to help with this task, additionally all of the request/server superglobals are iterable so rather than set up a conditional chain you can loop them and avoid repetitive code.

#### PHP

```
<?php
$newRecord = false;
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    try {
        list($errors, $inputs) = cleanInputs($_POST);

        if (!$errors['valid']) {
            throw new Exception(json_encode($errors));
        }
        
        // using instantiation in the same file for the example.
        $mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'password', 'schema');
        if (!$mysqli) {
            throw new Exception("({$mysqli->connect_errno}) {$mysqli->connect_error}");
        }
        // why is your form asking for Gender and URL if you aren't using them?
        $insertQuery = "INSERT INTO subscriptions (Name, Email, Comment, Subscription) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($insertQuery);

        if (!$stmt) {
            throw new Exception("({$mysqli->errno}) {$mysqli->error}");
        }
        
        $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $inputs['Name'], $inputs['Email'], $inputs['Comment'], $inputs['Subscription']);
        $stmt->execute();

        $newRecord = ($stmt->affected_rows > 0) ? 'Record added to database' : 'Record failed to insert to database';
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Here is where you would set your error variables for the html form.
        error_log($e);
    }
}

function cleanInputs($inputs)
{
    $keys = ['Name', 'Email', 'Website', 'Comment', 'Subscription',];
    $clean = [];
    $errors = ['valid' => true];
    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        if (empty($inputs[$key])) {
            $errors[$key] = "{$key} is required";
            $errors['valid'] = false;
            continue;
        }
        if (in_array($key, ['Name', 'Comment', 'Subscription', 'Gender'])) {
            $clean[$key] = trim(filter_var($inputs[$key], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
            continue;
        } else if ($key === 'Email') {
            $filter = filter_var($inputs[$key], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
            if (!$filter) {
                $errors[$key] = 'Invalid email format';
                $errors['valid'] = false;
                continue;
            }
            $clean[$key] = trim($filter);
        } else if ($key === 'Website') {
            $filter = filter_var($inputs[$key], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
            if (!$filter) {
                $errors[$key] = 'Invalid URL Format';
                $errors['valid'] = false;
                continue;
            }
            $clean[$key] = trim($filter);
        }
    }
    return [$errors, $clean];
}
?>
```

#### Edit

Expanding to help answer below question.

The cleanInputs() method will return both clean keys and any errors, so from there in your catch you would need to fill those error variables in. I would probably suggest setting default input values at the top of the file before processing and then resetting them in the error handler if they need to exist.

```
<?php 
$newRecord = false;
$name = ''; 
$email = ''; 
$website = ''; 
$comment = ''; 
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
// ... back to original example
```

then update your HTML with some error handler conditionals, use [alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) (personal opinion here, looks cleaner to me if you have to put logic into your templating)

```
<label for="Name">Name: </label>
<input type="text" name="Name" value="<?= $name ?>">
<?php if (isset($nameErr) && $nameErr !== false) : ?>
  <span class="error">* <?= $nameErr ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
<br><br>
```

and update your catch statement

```
} catch (Exception $e) {
  if (!$errors['valid']) {
    // repeat for errors.
     $nameErr = (isset($errors['Name'])) ? $errors['Name'] : false;
     if (!$nameErr) {
       $name .= $inputs['Name'];
     }
  }

  error_log($e);
}
```

Comment: @D Lowther Thanks for all the insight. As I am new to php I am still working through the basics. I was reviewing through your code (answer) and was wondering if in the below comment you wrote if I need to modify html variables on the form, and what I should call them as?          } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Here is where you would set your error variables for the html form.
        error_log($e);

Comment: In the cleanInputs method you'll note that it returns both a clean inputs array and an errors array. If you hit the catch block you would need to iterate through the errors array (and probably the clean values array to set echoable variables. you could use what you have now, you'd just have to set it. I'll add an edit with an example.